# internet not working in ubuntu 16.04 lts after connecting to lumia 540 phone

Tags: wireless, internet

Is there anybody who can help me resolve this long annoying issue.

CONCERN : internet not works after connecting to Lumia phone 540 in Ubuntu 16.04 lts. But when I connect to other wifi, it's works perfectly. Is there any compatibility issue?

Please suggest me.

Comment: Connecting how? Are you trying to use the Lumia as a tether, is it Bluetooth connection. Or is the Lumia a hotspot. Can other computers connect to it.

Comment: As a hotspot and after connecting to it, internet works for merely 10 minutes and then it shows there is no internet connection on chromium despite of full network.

Comment: Yes, on others computer its working properly.